# Can't execute sh file on embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded, android

I had no idea what firmware is this but it is a modified huawei firmware for a router. I needed a  better firewall Domain name control since huawei only give 16 domain slots to be blocked. I can't afford a Pi right not but Ive managed to install openVPN Cli with custom Ui to it. No I a trying to install Pi hole on it and push all the files to /tmp in the router storage through ADB so I am guessing the firmware is sort of android Linux. Now I have access as well to Telnet but not ssh as its as modified firmware. I installed busybox as well successfully that provides me additional tools to it. I have no problems with installation that dont require root access except Pi hole which needed to have one.

tried using

```
root@android:/tmp/Pihole/install # sh basic-install.sh
basic-install.sh[104]: stty: not found
```

I tried  as well using adb shell sh as it works with my other sh scripts

```
~/Downloads  adb push Pihole /tmp/                                                                                                                                            
ok | % | 11:48:46 PM 
Pihole/: 125 files pushed, 0 skipped. 0.6 MB/s (754810 bytes in 1.141s)
~/Downloads  adb shell sh /tmp/Pihole/install/basic-install.sh                                                                                                                
ok | % | 11:52:02 PM 
/tmp/Pihole/install/basic-install.sh[104]: stty: not found
~/Downloads  adb exec sh /tmp/Pihole/install/basic-install.sh
```

This is the only info I have,

```
root@android:/tmp/Pihole/install # busybox uname -r
3.4.5
root@android:/tmp/Pihole/install # busybox uname                                                                                                                                
Linux

Linux version 3.4.5 (jenkins@localhost) (gcc version 4.6.x-google 
20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 PREEMPT Sun May 5 15:57:03 CST 2019
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post similar questions. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874951) According to https://docs.pi-hole.net/main/prerequisites/, Android is not a supported operating system for Pi-hole.

Comment: On line 104 of `basic-install.sh` the stty(1) command is called and that command does not exist on your machine.